# I have a fruit fly problem

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've add fruit flies raising a garden every year I am very familiar with them and how to kill them. But twice now I have killed one by smashing it and upon doing so two little tiny bugs or crawling on me after I smashed the fruit fly and wiped it off of my hand. I am curious of what these little tiny bugs are that are living on the fruit fly. Can you help me identify them[![

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the picture is too blurry, so I can only talk from experience : They might be parasitic mites. Insects often carry parasitic mites around.
Look at this article for example :
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10317784/
It seems like Drosophila is no exception.

Moreover in this article :
https://www.jneurosci.org/content/36/44/11275
you can see that Drosophila has evolved a defense mechanism against such mites.

Parasitic mites of insects breach the cuticle and suck the hemolymph (equivalent of the blood + lymph of insects) out of their host.